# How to identify and remove errors in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

After some searching, I did not find a solution to the following problem, which in my thinking should have some very easy/efficient solution.

I'm looking at a list of images (faces), that I want to conform via `FindFaces`

```
faces = 
  ConformImages[HistogramTransform @ ImageTrim[#, FindFaces[#][1]]]& /@ images, 
    ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"]
```

So far this works like a charm and can also be found here: 
$\quad \quad $https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/GenderClassification.html

PROBLEM: The problem is that `FindFaces` is unable to detect some images and thus creates an error. This error is carried forward into the results list.

GOAL: Essentially I want to simply drop the error from the list. I also need to extract the position of those images to drop corresponding values from a secondary variable.

As the initial problem is not reproducible, here my idea as a very simplified example:

```
results = Table[1/i, {i, -5, 5}]
results[[6]]
posDrop = 6
resultsClean = Delete[results, posDrop]
```

The 6th value of the list returns the error message "ComplexInfinity". To somehow extract the position (i.e. 6) would suffice, but I'm looking for a solution that does not require me to know the specific error message or, for the image problem, finding non-numeric entries.

Comment: Seen `DeleteCases[]`?

Comment: Yes saw it; A) is there a generalized form for "pattern" to identify errors, e.g. sth. like "IsError/IsWarning". B) I need to know which cases had been dropped by the function. Many thanks.

Comment: If you need to know the position, look at `Position`.

Comment: Well, the idea of patterns is that you have to know exactly what you like (or don't, as the case may be). So, something like `DeleteCases[list, _DirectedInfinity]` will strip out any infinite results in `list`, since the pattern in the second argument captures how infinities are represented in *Mathematica*.

Comment: P.S. `Cases[]` and `DeleteCases[]` are complementary functions when given the same list and pattern.

Comment: Is there some definition of _pattern_ in 'Cases[]' or 'Position[]' that identifies errors/warnings? E.g. sth. similar to 'Position[Table[1/i, {i, -2, 2}], **_Error**]'?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "error/warning"?  Can you show an example in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Check` to return a particular value if an error is raised.

```
(* Here I return the string 'Error' which I can use to find the position of the errors. *)
test[x_] := Check[1/x, "Error"]; 
range = Range[-1,1,1];
ans = test/@range;(*Division by zero will raise a warning.*)
errPos = Position[ans,"Error"];
ans = Delete[ans,errPos];
range = Delete[range,errPos];
```

Edit: Check actually checks for all printed out messages. If you know you get a particular type of failure from your function, you can specify the message you want `Check` to respond to. In the case of dividing by zero you'd add `Power::infy` as the third argument, etc.

Comment: You can also use `Check[1/x, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]` to have `test` delete the item itself: in this case `ans` would have the desired result.

Comment: I really like that, I think it'll come in handy! +1 From OP's point of view, it doesn't keep track of which images failed though. Doing something like `MapIndexed[Check[{First[#2],f[#1]},Unevaluated@Sequence[]], images]`, where `f[x_]:= whatever image operations you want` would probably be perfect.